# Unable to get screen shot in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

I recently updated my Android Studio to version 3.1.4.  Since then, I am unable to get a screen shot by clicking the camera icon in Android Studio and I get the following message:

"Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EO"

I have tried getting screenshots from several devices, but each time I get this error.

I am able to run and debug across ADB without any problem and my devices are recognized by Android Studio.

May or may not be related... but I first noticed the problem after trying to capture an image from an emulator displaying a 3D model in OpenGL.  The emulator and Android Studio both froze on the computer and I had to kill the process from Windows Task Manager.

Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: don't know reason but you can try updating to android studio 3.2

Comment: restart android studio and check again

Comment: have you tried getting screenshot from a new AVD?

Comment: Try to restart Android studio and AVD if its not working update Android studio with 3.2

Comment: I get the same message when trying to capture from real devices and the emulator.  I downgraded my Android Studio to 2.3.3 and now I'm getting the same error in that IDE, as well.  Tried restarting my computer (and Android Studio) and my test devices but no glory.